# Is it reliable to use an unowned(unsafe) reference while the object in question is deinitializing?

Tags: swift

### Update

To clarify, the access of the object during its deinitialization is not being done in its `deinit` method explicitly. The object in question has listers that get added to it (closures) and these closures are all executed within the `deinit` method. It is within these closures that accesses of the object is being performed with `unowned` references. And it is the replacement of those `unowned` references with `unowned(unsafe)` references that results in `EXC_BAD_ACCESS'` from no longer occuring.

It is *these* `unowned(unsafe)` references that I'm referring to when asking if they're safe to use if always executed during the object in question's `deinit`.

### Original

I wrote a lot of code predicated on being able to clean up `unowned` references in the deinitializers of their `unowned` object. Lo and behold, that is not a feature of `unowned` references. But apparently it is of `unowned(unsafe)` references, at least that is the way it appears to be working right now — what once caused a crash accessing an `unowned` reference during its object's deinitialization, now is no longer crashing and is working as expected.

If guaranteed that all `unowned` references will not be accessed after deinitialization of their object, would it be safe to use it?

For more details, the aforementioned cleaning up entails removing the object from a set where the hashability is based off its contents' object identities. So if it's a plain `unowned` reference, when the set attempts to access its hash, it will crash if that procedure is being performed while the object is already deinitializing.

The reason the objects aren't removed from the set before they are deinitialized is because this code is a component of library that enables the addition of nodes to a directed acyclic graph. As a feature, I decided that I would not require consumers of the library to have to remove the nodes when they're done with them, they can simply add them to the graph, then when they're done, release their object (the node) as they would anyways, and because the library adds listeners onto the nodes to remove them from the graph in their deinitializers, it was anticipated that it wouldn't be a problem — that the graph would be able to be cleaned up transparently. Obviously it's a little more complicated now that it's apparent that `unowned(safe)` references can't be accessed while the object they're referencing is deinitializing.

If `unowned(unsafe)` works in the way it appears to, it would be a solution to this problem.

Comment: add weak instead unowned.

Comment: @luffy_064 there is an expectation throughout the code base that accesses will not return optional values. i would prefer to not have to refactor all that — implementing a separate execution path in each case for the scenario where the object has already been deinitialized — if `unowned(unsafe)` will get the job done with hardly any refactoring.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "clean up `unowned` references in the deinitializers of their `unowned` object". Can you show some code to demonstrate that?

Comment: @Sweeper I edited the question to touch on what the cleaning up entails (last paragraph).

Comment: @cristian_064 Not possible.  `weak` is already set to `nil` **before** your code's `deinit` starts running.  Likewise, `unowned`/`unowned(safe)` will already be switched over to assert before your `deinit` code is given a chance to run.

Comment: @Sweeper Here's a simple example: Your class uses a struct propertyWrapper that has an `unowned(unsafe) var owner!` that points back to the owning class (and thus, as a struct the memory allocation it's part of and has the same lifespan as).  The class's deinit needs to talk to the propertyWrapper one last time to do some cleanup— closing remote connections, serializing state, sending a signal to a remote object, etc. (there's thousands of use-cases for clean-up on deinit that goes outside the bounds of the current process's memory).

Comment: **+1** Good question, with good answers.  I'm not sure what's with the downvotes— Swift's `unowned` specifier works differently from most C-like language's pointers/references (Obj-C, C++, C#, Java, etc.), and Swift's `deinit` process is likewise different for most C-like languages.  There's important distinctions in what you can and can't do relative to nearly every other OO language, which the question grapples with and the answers explain well.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between `unowned(safe)` and `unowend(unsafe)` is that the *save* variant is implemented using proxy objects and it will reliably crash your app when you access it illegally.

The *unsafe* variant on the other hand is just a plain C-Style pointer which will sometimes "just work" (if by coincidence the memory has not been reused anyway) and sometimes will strangely crash or just report unpredicable results.

`unowned` is the same as `unowned(safe)`

Nevertheless, during `deinit` you may access all the propertys of your object, see [The Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Deinitialization.html)

And also:

Comment: from what i've read thus far, you may access all the properties of your object during `deinit` from *within* the deinitializer. my question pertains to the access of deinitializing objects external to the deinitializer, while it's in progress. in other words, closures are provided to the object in question, and these closures are executed inside its `deinit`, and also access that object using a captured `unowned` reference to it. doing so, i've found that if the captured `unowned` reference is `safe` then it fails every time, but so far as i've tested, using `unsafe` succeeds every time.

Comment: right, but if the object is actively deinitializing then is it safe to assume that the memory has not been reused, and therefore that the object will still be accessible via these `unowned(unsafe)` references?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you have implemented but it looks like you are trying to duplicate the mechanism with tables Swift uses internally for keeping track of deallocations of [weak references](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2017-09-22-swift-4-weak-references.html).

> If guaranteed that all unowned references will not be accessed after
> deinitialization of their object, would it be safe to use it?

Yes it would be safe. If you have this guarantee I think it would also be simpler to turn all your variables to implicitly unwrapped weak variables.

> So if it's a plain unowned reference, when the set attempts to access
> its hash, it will crash if that procedure is being performed while the
> object is already deinitializing.
>
> Obviously it's a little more complicated now that it's apparent that
> unowned(safe) references can't be accessed while the object they're
> referencing is deinitializing.

I do not think this is the reason for the crash, the memory is freed after  deinitialization, during deinitialization you still have access to the instance to perform any manual cleanup you need, I would suggest to replace the complicated solution that keeps track of deallocated references, and simply rely on Swift to set to nil objects that are deallocated using weak references. If you do not want to refactor you code to handle optionals when make them explicitly unwrapped.

However **if during deinitialization you access the object from an other reference(outside deinit) it will fail**, this is to ensure consistency. See [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/cfe0b9774d8fe54504615496d0ca75337d06c372/stdlib/public/runtime/HeapObject.cpp#L677) that access an instance that is deinitialized will cause an app to crash.

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify that what I am doing is using `unowned` references from outside of the body of the `deinit`; albeit during its execution. I've found that `unowned(unsafe)` works as if it allows access to the underlying deinitializing object outside of the body of the `deinit`. And I'm wondering if this is something I can rely on.

Comment: Swift for safety reasons checks if during deinitialization you access the object from an other reference(outside deinit) and aborts execution(see the link in my answer). The unowned(unsafe) obviously does not perform the above safety checks, which means that it will appear to work. With the scenario that you describe it should work everytime(since they are accessed from the deinit), but I would strongly suggest to find a safer way to achieve the same results, a change int he future might break your implementation.